# Isomorphism between 2nd symmetric product and Jacobian

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, jacobians, modular-curves

Let $X=X_0(N)$ be hyperelliptic with $g(X)\geq 2$ with $\infty$ as a cusp and $\iota$ as the hyperelliptic involution. Then the map 
$$X^{(2)} \longrightarrow Jac(X)$$ $$D \longrightarrow [D-\infty -\iota(\infty)]$$ is an isomorphism away from the fibre of $0$.

I showed that this map is injective away from the fibre of $0$ but I am not able to show the surjectivity.

If we can show that for any degee zero non principal divisor $D$, $l(D+\infty +\iota(\infty))\ne 0.$ But I don't know how to show the this Riemann Roch space is non-zero. Even assuming the space is zero, I am not able to find any contradiction.

Can anyone please give me any hint?

Comment: It is surjective if and only if the dimension of $Jac(X)$ — that is, the genus of $X$ — is 2.

Comment: The $g$-th symmetric product is birational to the Jacobian. See Milne's article on Jacobians in the conference proceedings edited by Cornell-Silverman. Also note that the dimension of $X^(2)$ is $2$ and the dimension of the Jacobian is $g$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The isomorphic part will be $l(D+\infty+\iota(\infty))\geq 1$, $D\in Jac(X)$.